# get an address column with stored addresses in every row to connect to another hyperlink column that opens up Googlemaps with address in that row

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I have a MySQL database open and running fine and I can store data great. I have an address column though with stored addresses in every row and I need to add another hyperlink column that opens up the stored address in that specific row in Google Maps.

```
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent1" 
runat="server">

 <form id="form1" runat="server" style=" background-color:#e2e6e9;  
margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width:95%; height:auto; max- 
height:100%;">
     <div>
              <tr style="background-color:#c5ccd3;">
                <td>
                    <asp:Label Text="Address" runat="server" />
                </td>
                <td colspan="2" style="background-color:#c5ccd3;">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Address" runat="server" />
                </td>
            </tr>
             <tr style="background-color:#c5ccd3;">
                <td>
                    <asp:Label Text="MAP" runat="server" />
                </td>
                <td colspan="2" style="background-color:#c5ccd3;">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="MAP" runat="server" />
                </td>
            </tr>
             <td></td>
             <td colspan="2" ><asp:Button Text="Save" ID="btnSave" 
              runat="server" 
              OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
              <asp:Button Text="Delete" ID="btnDelete" runat="server" 
              OnClick="btnDelete_Click" />
              <asp:Button Text="Clear" ID="btnClear" runat="server" 
              OnClick="btnClear_Click" />
              </td>
              <asp:GridView ID="Clientview" runat="server" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
              OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" style="background- 
              color:#c5ccd3;" 
              >
              <Columns>
              <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" />
              <asp:BoundField DataField="MAP" HeaderText="MAP" />
              </Columns>
              </asp:GridView> 
              </div>
         `    </form> 
<!--I have plenty of C# code Behind code also and cannot figure this out 
for the life of me for some reason. Wasted 8 + hours trying already.-->
```

Just Address column has stored Addresses and need MAP column to become link to Google Maps that automatically opens up with address in the same row, and for every row that will have a different address.